# Jenkins Cannot create token using login and password

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

[image: Jenkins create token failing]

I was trying to set up git pipeline, but for some reason, I am unable to do so now.
It is throwing error showing the above error. I tried different things, but could not see anything out of the order.

I am at my wits end and do not know how to proceed. Kindly tell me how should I proceed to fix this ?.

Note:-
Currently Jenkins is installed in an ec2 instance and another ec2 instance is used as build server, in both servers git is installed and working correctly.
I have sshed into build server and tried accessing repo from it and was able to clone the repo sucessfully in build server.

Kindly advise me on what might be the possible issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using basic username/password combination, GitHub no longer supports basic authentication using a username and password for the API and Git operations.

https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth

https://github.blog/2020-07-30-token-authentication-requirements-for-api-and-git-operations/

Instead, you'll have to use personal access tokens (PAT). Web browser based sign ins to GitHub will still use your username and password, all others will require a token.

Comment: I was unable to use login and password authentication. I am not sure if this is because of the reason your mentioned, if it's true, I will accept this as the answer . I had to create token authentication for the webhook. And got it working.